# How to send multiple mails in PHP?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send email from a database. I get email from the databse and send message to email I get from database.

My code is working good, but I have problem the sending mail - it is only sent for the first one.

```
include("config.php");
include ("library.php"); 
include ("classes/class.phpmailer.php");


$sql = "select * from Table ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 if ($row['Date_Registry'] == date("Y-m-d") ){ 
$sql= "select * from write_message where ID='$m'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$email=  $row['EMAIL'];
$masg = $row['Write_message'];
$Message_name = $row['Message_name'];
    $email = $email;
    $mail   = new PHPMailer; // call the class 
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST; //Hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = SMTP_UNAME; //Username for SMTP authentication any valid email created in your domain
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PWORD; //Password for SMTP authentication
    $mail->SetFrom(SMTP_UNAME, "Helli"); //From address of the mail
    // put your while loop here like below,
    $mail->Subject = $Message_name; //Subject od your mail
    $mail->AddAddress($email); //To address who will receive this email

}
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to call a `send()` method or something?

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the function clearAddress above the AddAddress function (as below) and it will work.

```
include("config.php");
include ("library.php"); 
include ("classes/class.phpmailer.php");


$sql = "select * from Table ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 if ($row['Date_Registry'] == date("Y-m-d") ){ 
$sql= "select * from write_message where ID='$m'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$email=  $row['EMAIL'];
$masg = $row['Write_message'];
$Message_name = $row['Message_name'];
    $email = $email;
    $mail   = new PHPMailer; // call the class 
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST; //Hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = SMTP_UNAME; //Username for SMTP authentication any valid email created in your domain
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PWORD; //Password for SMTP authentication
    $mail->SetFrom(SMTP_UNAME, "Helli"); //From address of the mail
    // put your while loop here like below,
    $mail->Subject = $Message_name; //Subject od your mail

    $this->phpMailerObj->clearAddresses(); //Clear Addresses

    $mail->AddAddress($email); //To address who will receive this email
    $this->phpMailerObj->Body = "body";
    $this->phpMailerObj->msgHTML("Message");
    try {
        $this->phpMailerObj->Send();
        return;
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        return $error['error'] = "Email cound not be sent";
    }

}
}
```